# Directive now causes "Can't bind to 'blur' since it isn't a known property of 'input'."

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-template

In our angular 4.3.2 project, we have a directive that `.trim()`s various types of inputs. In its entirety:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, forwardRef, HostBinding, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from "@angular/forms";

const TRIM_VALUE_ACCESSOR = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => TrimDirective),
  multi: true
};

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[type=text]:not(#autocomplete-keyboard-access):not([disabled]):not(.dropdown-box), input[type=email]',
  providers: [TRIM_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})

export class TrimDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange = (_: any) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @HostBinding('blur')
  blur() {
    this.onTouched();
  }

  @HostBinding('change')
  trim(value: any): void {
    if (value) {
      value = value.toString().trim();
    }

    this.writeValue(value);
    this.onChange(value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => any): void { this.onChange = fn; }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => any): void { this.onTouched = fn; }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (typeof value !== 'undefined') {
      this.renderer.setProperty(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', value);
    }
  }
}
```

It is imported into the relevant `@NgModule`. Similarly, `FormsModule` exists in the `NgModule.imports[]`.

In templates, I now have the following error at template compile time (be it in the browser or AoT):

> Can't bind to 'blur' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

The error is thrown wherever the directive applies.

A template in question (which dates back to *beta-6* days and has not been refactored since):

```html
<input #userEmail
       name="email"
       type="email"
       class="modal-fixed-width-input" maxLength="128"
       required
       placeholder="email@domain.com"
       pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"
       [ngClass]="{'bg-yellow red' : !emailFocus && emailErrorMessage}"
       [(ngModel)]="userMail"
       (ngModelChange)="fieldsChange=true"
       ngControl="email"
       #email="ngModel"
       (focus)="emailFocus=true"
       (blur)="emailFocus=false; userEmail.value = userEmail.value.trim(); emailErrorMessage = isEntryValid(userEmail.value, 'Email');">
```

Before transitioning to Angular CLI, this directive worked. Since `FormsModule` is correctly imported (which is usually the explanation for this error) I'm at a loss to explain why this directive's event listener bindings cause this compilation error.

Comment: I may say something silly, pardon me please. I think maybe there is name collision for blur in hostbinding. Could you test @HostBinding('blur')
  onBlur() {....

Comment: @Vega Not a silly guess, frameworks often do this sort of name binding, but the real problem is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `blur` and `change` properties on `input` element.

I guess you are looking for `@HostListener`

```
@HostListener('blur')
....
@HostListener('change')
```

The `@HostListener` decorator lets you subscribe to events of the host element while

`@HostBinding` will bind property to host element

Comment: he probably confused hostbinding with hostlitner, maybe add some details about the confusion?

Comment: D'oh! Yes, I caught _this exact bug_ in a number of other legacy components and missed this one. What's odd is that this compiled prior to using `ng` to compile the UI. Any extra thoughts on why that might be?